# Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type address

Tags: solidity, erc-20

```
        owner = msg.sender();
```

It gives me 2 errors

```
Type tuple() is not implicitly convertible to expected type address
```

and

```
Type is not callable
```

I'm just trying to do a simple ERC20

Compile with

```
        owner = msg.sender;
```

But I think I want to use the ().

Comment: Have you declared `address owner` anywhere???

Comment: Why do you want to use the ()? Does it make you so happy? :-)

Comment: I did   address public owner; in the contract ownable. I don't know lol I am following a tutorial and the guy used () and it compiled...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`owner = msg.sender;` is right. `msg.sender` isn't a function, so you shouldn't try to call it.

Comment: Oh ok because in the tutorial I am following he is using () and it compiles... Or maybe he deleted the () and cutted the video and assumed we got it right...